# Why does model.predict() only provide a single prediction of all test data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, predict

Basing my code in the folowing article:
https://medium.com/@polanitzer/how-to-guess-accurately-3-lottery-numbers-out-of-6-using-lstm-model-e148d1c632d6
I tried to make a model with the same structure, witch is the following:

```
model=keras.Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240, input_shape = (tamaño_ventana, num_features), return_sequences = True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240, input_shape=(
    tamaño_ventana, num_features), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240, input_shape=(
    tamaño_ventana, num_features), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(240, input_shape=(
    tamaño_ventana, num_features), return_sequences=False)))
model.add(Dense(59))
model.add(Dense(num_features))
```

Where the variables are defined as follows:

```
num_filas=df_train.values.shape[0]
tamaño_ventana=7#cantidad de sorteos a tener en cuenta en la predicción
num_features=df_train.values.shape[1]#número de bolas por sorteo
```

I trained the model with a 80% of the full data i have available. The 20% resting is thought to be used for the testing.
When compiling and asking the model to make a prediction, the returned value is only one prediction. This is, is taking for predicting only one row and the rest is not predicted. Therefore i can't compare that 20% of data with the predicted values.
Any ideas on why does it make it?

```
y_pred = loaded_model.predict(np.array([df_transformada_test]))
print("The predicted numbers in the last lottery game are:", scaler_test.inverse_transform(y_pred).astype(int)[0])
prediction = np.array(df_test.tail(1))
print("The actual numbers in the last lottery game were:", prediction[0])
```

(df_transformada_test is the value of the transformed array to the correct shape of that 20% of test_data)

Comment: You are passing only one element (e.g df_test.tail(1))

Comment: The element im passing is for comparing, that one is not predicted. Im passing an array with all the data in 
loaded_model.predict(np.array([df_transformada_test]))
@Dr.Snoopy

Comment: You are taking the first prediction in astype(int)[0], maybe just print y_pred.shape to confirm that all predictions are being made.

Comment: y_pred.shape is (1,7). Witch means that its only predicting one row. Im a little confused.

Comment: And the shape of df_transformada_test?

Comment: The shape is (7,7). I hope it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: The problem is this: [df_transformada_test] , pass it without brackets as it is being interpreted as a single sample.

Comment: An error raised:
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

    Input 0 of layer "bidirectional" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 7)

    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 7), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None